# Using Node.js EventEmitter without subclassing

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

Is it possible to use Node.js EventEmitter in two different files without subclassing the EventEmitter?

I have tried this:

File1.js

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var emitter = new EventEmitter();

emitter.emit('eventFromFile1');
```

File2.js

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var emitter = new EventEmitter();

emitter.on('eventFromFile1', function(){
    console.log('Received event'); // Never happens
});
```

This does not work. I guess that is because two instances of the event emitter exists and they are not connected.

Can I achieve similar behaviour without subclassing the EventEmitter?

(I am new to Node.js)

Comment: You need to export your instance of the first emitter and require it in `File2.js`.

Comment: how would *subclassing* (?) help you?

Comment: Right, I can just export the emitter in File1 and use that in File2, instead of creating a new instance. Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 1):

No need to subclass, you just need to use the same event emitter. In your example you have two different event emitters.

Like this:

File1.js

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var emitter = module.exports.emitter = new EventEmitter();

emitter.on('my_event', function(){
    console.log('Received event'); // Never happens
});
```

File2.js

```
var emitter = require('./File1.js').emitter;
emitter.emit('my_event');
```

Comment: Thank you!, This fixed the error that I was having too.